# Publish app for Chromecast without a receiver application

Tags: android, chromecast, mirroring, screencast

As stated in Google cast [Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers), I need a sender application and a receiver application in order to publish an app for Chromecast. My app uses [Presentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html) class to show contents on Chromecast when the device is mirrored to the Chromecast. Yes, the app only works on devices which can cast its screen onto Chromecast. I am not using any kind of receiver application for my app. Can I still publish my app for ChromeCast so that it can appear in [apps section](https://www.google.com/chrome/devices/chromecast/apps.html) for Chromecast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you need to be using a receiver of your own (either a Styled receiver or a custom one) to be able to tag an app as a cast app.

Comment: Thanks. Can a layout be displayed in Chromecast using default receiver?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a layout but both the Default and Styled receivers are aimed at media playback and the styled one is the same as the default one except that you can provide your own CSS which can customize/brand your receiver. Anything beyond that requires a custom receiver but also remember that if you are using the Presentation APIs with mirroring, you are not using any of these receivers so there is no way to customize that. nor you can write a custom one for mirroring.